# Цитаты из Евангелия и Корана

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие, пробелы

Цитата из Евангелия –  **(Матф. 2:5)**;
цитата из Корана – **(2:5)**.

Нужен ли пробел после двоеточия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подробные инструкции здесь: [ОФОРМЛЕНИЕ ПЕЧАТНЫХ МАТЕРИАЛОВ НА БИБЛЕЙСКУЮ ТЕМАТИКУ](http://helpforheart.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Spravochnoe_rukovodstvo_HfH_1.1.18.pdf). В частности, примеры ссылок на с. 17:

> Мк. 2:7
>   Мф. 3:4–6,8

Мф. — Евангелие от Матфея

Answer (score 2):

Пробел не нужен.

Знак, о котором говорится здесь и который лучше называть **разделителем**, не употребляется с функцией двоеточия, как это происходит в тексте. Также условным образом разделяются в разных сферах математические символы, в том числе числа для записи времени дня (23:55:12), где разделитель ставится между разными единицами измерения.

В этом случае, что важно для типографики, двоеточие-разделитель имеет как строчную форму, так и заглавную, выровненную по высоте прописных букв. Последняя предпочти­тель­на при исполь­зо­ва­нии с цифрами.

Comment: Символ этот называется **двоеточием**.  У Мильчина: "стандарт требует ставить двоеточие: 23:30:10 (23 часа 30 минут 10 секунд)". Там ссылка на ГОСТ

Comment: Читайте внимательно: не «не называется», а «не употребляется с функцией двоеточия», как в тексте.

Comment: Двоеточие — знак, а не функция. Двоеточие может выполнять в тексте разные функции.

Comment: Читайте внимательно, не возражайте тому, как поняли. Я где-то назвал двоеточие функцией?

Comment: @shampar Вы знаете, а я Вас поддержу! Вопрос стоял так: **нужен ли пробел после двоеточия**? Вы абсолютно правильно сказали - нет, не нужен. (Только, наверное, надо было по-другому: не употребляется в функции **обычного пунктуационного** двоеточия - как в обычных атеистических текстах.)

Comment: @shampar, Это интересно с точки зрения русского языка. Как понимать слова "Знак... не употребляется с функцией двоеточия"? Фраза построена, скажем так, не очень корректно. Понять ее можно двояко. Вариант 1. Знак не выполняет функцию под названием двоеточие. На это отвечаю, то двоеточие не функция . Вариант 2. Знак не выполняет функцию двоеточия. На это отвечаю, что у двоеточия не одна, а много функций. Далее,двоеточие и есть знак (:), и в обозначении времени — двоеточие, и в математике знак деления — двоеточие.  Есть разные функции. А в данном примере двоеточие выполняет одну из своих функций.

Comment: Именно это и хотел сказать. Только в  двух строчках. Двоеточие есть знак со многими ролями — от текста до различных условных форм. Отдельное Послание Римме М.: В текстах сакральных двоеточие есть и было, и оттуда пришло в «атеистические», если уж по порядку вещей. Спасибо всем.